# Sorting issue excel

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-2010

I have the following sample of products which are manufactured as specified on that date in the same order

```
7-Mar-15    RTA
7-Mar-15    RTA
9-Mar-15    RTA
9-Mar-15    NZC
9-Mar-15    NZC
10-Mar-15   NZC
10-Mar-15   NZC
10-Mar-15   LBA
11-Mar-15   LBA
11-Mar-15   LBA
12-Mar-15   LBA
12-Mar-15   LBB
12-Mar-15   PXA
13-Mar-15   PXA
13-Mar-15   GNA
14-Mar-15   GNA
16-Mar-15   GNA
16-Mar-15   GNA
17-Mar-15   GNA
```

I have sorted data (A to Z) based on Column B to get the data as below. The idea was to group all the same products and make a "modification" to date

```
13-Mar-15   GNA
14-Mar-15   GNA
16-Mar-15   GNA
16-Mar-15   GNA
17-Mar-15   GNA
10-Mar-15   LBA
11-Mar-15   LBA
11-Mar-15   LBA
12-Mar-15   LBA
12-Mar-15   LBB
9-Mar-15    NZC
9-Mar-15    NZC
10-Mar-15   NZC
10-Mar-15   NZC
12-Mar-15   PXA
13-Mar-15   PXA
7-Mar-15    RTA
7-Mar-15    RTA
9-Mar-15    RTA
```

Post modification i wanted the sort the data by Date (Oldest to newest) by the order is all messed up as below

```
7-Mar-15    RTA
7-Mar-15    RTA
9-Mar-15    NZC
9-Mar-15    NZC
9-Mar-15    RTA
10-Mar-15   LBA
10-Mar-15   NZC
10-Mar-15   NZC
11-Mar-15   LBA
11-Mar-15   LBA
12-Mar-15   LBA
12-Mar-15   LBB
12-Mar-15   PXA
13-Mar-15   GNA
13-Mar-15   PXA
14-Mar-15   GNA
16-Mar-15   GNA
16-Mar-15   GNA
17-Mar-15   GNA
```

If you compare the first data set and third data set you will find the dates are in order but observe row 3, date is same but order of product is different.

I wanted the data to look like my first data set.

I have tried the option to Add level in sorting but it did not work. Any leads on how can solve this issue?

Comment: There is no way to get sorted like in first dataset, if your first dataset wasn't initially sorted according to any condition. If you want further solution, just add another number ordered column to your first table.

Answer (score 0):

you sort the data goto DATA menu click on Sort then add level first level keep product & secound level keep date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

1. Sort **column B** (Sort Z to A)
2. Sort **column A** (Oldest to Newest)

Comment: Its not working. I am getting the same result as in Data set 3

Comment: for me its different and somewhat similar to Set 1.

Comment: what is your expected o/p BTW ?

Comment: The data set 1 represent the actual date when a product is manufactured. A change in the product represent a change over time, for example if you see row 3 and 4 the date is same but there is changeover time that is added with the process time. In column C i have inserted formula that tracks number of changeover and the time  it has taken to changeover. In data set 2 i have to reduce the change overs by clubbing same products together. Once it is done, i have to sort it back to original data set to identify the total time. But as you see in data set 3 the whole data is distributed randomly

Comment: I'm afraid but what you're trying to do is not possible with simple date and string sort. There has to be a time stamp instead which can help you to sort based on the entries.